# Search for coordinates and change triangle color in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm working on Delaunay triangulation using OpenGL in C++. I have already set the mesh now i'm looking for a way to change the color of a triangle after finding it's coordinates (x,y), i already have an idea on how to search for (x,y) but how to change the color of the triangle after finding it is where i'm stuck at.

```
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.5, 0.5);
    list<Tri*>::iterator iter;
    Tri* triangle;
    int v1, v2, v3;
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    for(iter = triangles.begin(); iter != triangles.end(); iter++)
    {
      triangle = *iter;
      v1 = triangle->v[0];  v2 = triangle->v[1];  v3 = triangle->v[2];
      // the part where i want to change the color:
      if(x[v1] == 1.06 && y[v1] == 7.28) {
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      } else {
        glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
      }

      glVertex2f(x[v1], y[v1]);
      glVertex2f(x[v2], y[v2]);
      glVertex2f(x[v3], y[v3]);  
    }
    glEnd();
```

After executing it all the triangles are in green meaning that it did not find the two points!!

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you'll have coordinates that are *exactly* 1.06 and 7.28. Might even be impossible, because a float can't represent those values exactly, and you're comparing the float values to double constants. In any case, without fully understanding what you're trying to do, you'll probably need to change the comparison to allow for a certain (small) range around those values.

Comment: i already have set these coordinates alongside 19 others! it's not random..

Comment: he means that `1.06f != 1.06` and `7.28f != 7.28`

Comment: @0x58: Also, you should not test for floating-point equality as Reto points out. You need a small epsilon value to account for things like rounding errors and the inability to perfectly represent certain numbers. So test for something like `x[v1] > 1.06f - 0.0001f && x[v1] < 1.06f + 0.0001f` instead of `x[v1] == 1.06f`. Epsilon is 0.0001f in this case, that gives you a tolerance of +/- 0.0001f, which is probably reasonably accurate.

Comment: Thank you i'll consider this.